# xslt- remove just a specific child

Tags: xslt

I have following xml

```html
<equationgroup>
  <equation>
    <MathFork>
      <Math>2*3</Math>
      <note>some note</note>
      <branch><Math>8^2</Math></branch>
    </MathFork>
  </equation>
</equationgroup>
```

I want to remove the Math subelement from MathFork but keep it for branch using xslt.

So the result should be:

```html
<equationgroup>
      <equation>
        <MathFork>
          <note>some note</note>
          <branch><Math>8^2</Math></branch>
        </MathFork>
      </equation>
    </equationgroup>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like matching template for everything and template for filtering out the unwanted node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple...

This preserve all of your elements:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

if you want remove "Math" element, only if is child of "MathFork" you can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="Math[parent::MathFork]"/>
```

Using local-name() I will try:

```
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'Math' and parent::*[local-name() = 'MathFork']]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying fast. <xsl:template match="Math[parent::MathFork]"/> is what I am looking for, but if I have namespace in xml, how can use the same statement with local-name()?